# Which Linux Distro has TARPIT out of the box?

Tags: security, iptables

I need TARPIT. Im worried to patch the kernel as it may result in unexpected problem.

So, Which Linux Distro has TARPIT out of the box?

thanks.

Comment: Tarpit isn't officially supported by the Netfilter maintainers so I don't see a big distro accepting it into the default kernel.  Compiling the kernel has become fairly painless these days, though of course is still extra work and will require recompiles every time you want a new kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Lucid, I found that I could install it pretty easily:

```
apt-get install module-assistant
module-assistant auto-install xtables-addons-source
```